# How to get the values from the table based on dates from datetime field django

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
import pymysql
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from facligo_app.models import Scrapper
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
import pytz



find_description = ""
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
        print(from_date)
        to_date = request.POST.get("to_date")
        print(to_date)
        roles =  Scrapper.objects.all()
        # for i in roles:
        #     print(i.description)
        global find_description
        find_description = Scrapper.objects.all().filter(created_at=from_date,updated_at=to_date)
        print(find_description)

    return render(request, "home.html", {"scrappers": find_description})

models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db import connections
# Create your models here.
class Scrapper(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "test_table_1"
```

From my form I will post data where my from_date = "2022-11-09" and to_date = "2022-11-09". But my table column has time with date. Is there any solution to get the data based on only date I post. But my table should not make any alter.

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oelpO.png)

Answer (score 0):

First convert the the given date to `datetime` object using `strptime`

Example

```
from_date = request.POST.get("from_date")
# For a datetime.datetime obj:
from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then you can use to filter.

```
find_description = Scrapper.objects.all().filter(created_at__date=from_date,updated_at__date=to_date)
```

Comment: When I add it is getting 2022-11-09 00:00:00. But my table structure has different time. And output I am getting RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Scrapper.updated_at received a naive datetime